# Angular FormControl validation with regex: textarea lines should not start with special characters

Tags: javascript, angular, regex

I have a textarea with a simple FormControl, which I'd like to validate via the Validators.pattern() method. None of the new lines should be started with a ? or *. That's all the requirements.

I've tried the following:

```
control = new FormControl('', Validators.pattern(/^(\?|\*)$/));
```

With this, I can validate the first line (works well if the line starts with a special character), but as soon as I hit enter my FormControl will be invalid.

How should I tweak the regex to meet the requirements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are dealing with a textarea you need to emulate the `\A` meta escape which is "start of **string** not line"

```regex
/(?<!\s)^(?![\s\S]*^[?*])/gm
```

- `(?<!\s)^` - detect the start of the string
- `(?![\s\S]*^[?*])` - Ahead of me cannot be any line which starts with a question mark nor asterisk

  - `[\s\S]*` - capture everything, even new lines
  - `^[?*]` - detect a line which starts with a question mark or asterisk

https://regex101.com/r/NacQst/1

Comment: This still allows me to begin the new line with an asterisk or a question mark.

Comment: @elyndel Make sure to supply the `/m` flag

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```js
// With a string literal where anchors are added automatically by Angular
control = new FormControl('', Validators.pattern('(?![?*]).*(?:[\r\n]+(?![?*]).*)*'));
// Or, with a regex literal
control = new FormControl('', Validators.pattern(/^(?![?*]).*(?:[\r\n]+(?![?*]).*)*$/));
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4nWe5n/1). *Details*:

- `^` - string start anchor
- `(?![?*])` - no `?` and `*` are allowed immediately to the right of the current location
- `.*` - zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group:

  - `[\r\n]+` - one or more CR / LF chars (carriage return or line feed chars)
  - `(?![?*]).*` - a line that does not start with `?` nor `*`
- `)*` - end of group, zero or more occurrences
- `$` - end of the string.